# How does the Stanford Parser handle unseen words?

Tags: java, parsing, stanford-nlp, vocabulary

I'm curious to know more about the heuristics/techniques used by the Stanford parser for handling unseen words.

For example, given input: `aa aaa aaaa, "bb bbb bbbb"?`, the parser produces: `(ROOT (SQ (VP (VB aa) (NP (NP (NN aaa) (NN aaaa)) (, ,) () (NP (NN bb) (NN bbb) (NN bbbb)) ('' ''))) (. ?)))`. As another example, given: `aaa aaaa`, the parser output is: `(ROOT (NP (NN aaa) (NN aaaa)))`. How does the parser parse these sentences?

I've looked on the [Stanford Parser FAQs](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/parser-faq.shtml) page as well as the parser mailing lists, but couldn't find any discussions on this topic.

Thanks in advance for any insights.